# How do I combine variables by name and then find the average of another variable based on that?

Tags: pandas, numpy, loops

[Data Set Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tLM3.jpg)
Attached in the picture is an example of my data set. For example the first value under Hunt name is Beaver. There are multiple instances of Beaver under Hunt name for different years. What I am trying to do is find the average '% success' for all the Hunt names. I know that I could this for each individual Hunt name manually but I am trying to find a faster way to do it all at once.

I have tried a few different things using Numpy but can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'HUNT_NAME' : ['Beaver', 'Deer', 'Moose', 'Beaver', 'Deer'],
    '%_SUCCESS' : [10, 5, 5, 20, 10]
})

df.groupby(['HUNT_NAME'], as_index = False)['%_SUCCESS'].agg('mean')
```

If not please provide more sample data as well as expected outcome

Comment: Okay so ultimately I ended up running this code: 
Newdf = df.groupby('Hunt name').mean() and it gave me the average of all other columns based on hunt name. Then I ran Newdf['% success'].nlargest(n=5) which gave me the top 5 % success based on Hunt name. However, now I am trying to create a barplot with these top 5 and I can't get it to work. Is there a way to create a new df from this? Sorry I'm probably very confusing. I don't know hardly any Python and am trying to get through a school project.